# Remove destination folder icon

Tags: inno-setup

How can I remove the folder icon that appears on the installation page?

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hide the respective component – `WizardForm.SelectDirBitmapImage`:

```pascal
[Code]

procedure InitializeWizard();
begin
  WizardForm.SelectDirBitmapImage.Visible := False;
end;
```